# Leaflet feature conditional svg styling

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

I'm new to Leaflet; I have a svg I'd like to style depending on info in the feature, but have no idea where to start.

Here is the svg:

```
<svg
  <g
   id="g2450">
  <rect
    x="0"
    y="0"
    width="60"
    height="80"
    fill="#0000ff"
    stroke="#0000ff"
    fill-opacity="0"
    id="rect2446" />
  <text
    x="2"
    y="15"
    font-family="Verdana"
    font-size="10px"
    fill="#0000ff"
    id="text2448">??</text>
  <g
    id="g2564"
    x="50%"
    y="50%"
    transform="matrix(0.51584178,0,0,0.51641502,11.648419,22.062229)">
  <path
   id="path2"
   class="ind"
   d="m 6.3,0.8 c -3,0 -5.5,2.5 -5.5,5.5 0,3 2.5,5.5 5.5,5.5 3,0 5.5,-2.5 5.5,-5.5 0,-3 -2.5,-5.5 -5.5,-5.5"
   fill="#dddddc" />
  <path
   id="path4"
   class="ind_start"
   d="m 6.3,0.8 c -3,0 -5.5,2.5 -5.5,5.5 0,3 2.5,5.5 5.5,5.5 3,0 5.5,-2.5 5.5,-5.5 0,-3 -2.5,-5.5 -5.5,-5.5"
   stroke-miterlimit="10"
   style="fill:none;stroke:#8e8e8e;stroke-width:1.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10" />
  <path
   id="path6"
   class="ind_on"
   d="M 6.3,3.5 C 4.7,3.5 3.5,4.8 3.5,6.3 3.5,7.8 4.8,9.1 6.3,9.1 7.9,9.1 9.1,7.8 9.1,6.3 9.1,4.8 7.8,3.5 6.3,3.5"
   fill="#dddddc" />
</g>
```

It looks like this: [image: svg image]

So, on each feature, I need to style the `rect` `fill` color, change the `text`, and color the circle thing.

So far, I've tried adding the svg as a `divIcon` but not got any further in my endeavours.

```
const svgTemplate = `<svg ... />
const icon = L.divIcon({
  className: "marker",
  html: svgTemplate,
});

let layer = L.Proj.geoJson (null, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: icon});
  },
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
     ...
  }
}).addTo (map);
```

I can see the `svg`s in the html - [image: html from chrome dev] but they don't seem to relate to a particular feature, so I can't style them from the DOM (?)

All help appreciated.

Comment: Based on *what* info of each `feature` are you trying to style the icons? If you have SVG's with different content, then I suggest you create multiple `L.divIcon` each with a different SVG and a class which controls the colors, fill, strokes, etc.